# How can I delete element then return him in function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays

I have function, that goes to return and delete last element from array, but if I delete this element, function could return null value

```
function poll(Queue storage _queue) public returns(Job job) {
    require(data.length==0);
    require(_queue.length - 1 < cursorPosition);
    _queue.cursorPosition++;
    // there should be element deleting
    return (_queue.jobArray[cursorPosition - 1]);
}
```

Comment: store the element in some temorary variable, delete it and return the temporary variable? have you tried that ?

Comment: right! Thank you. Could you make an answer, so I can check it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cost-effective way to do this, as [the delete type](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#delete) behave like an assignation to the default value, thus returning a zero-like value.

As @Med Mansour told you above, store the value in a variable and then return said variable.